# How Replace a dot (.) in sentence except when it appears in an abbreviation using regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, nlp, data-cleaning, python-re

I want to replace every dot with a space in a sentence except when it is used with an abbreviation. When it is used with an abbreviation, I want to replace it with `''` NULL.

Abbreviation means a dot surrounded at least two Capital letters.

My `regex` are working except they catch `U.S.`

```
r1 = r'\b((?:[A-Z]\.){2,})\s*'
r2 = r'(?:[A-Z]\.){2,}'

'U.S.A is abbr  x.y  is not. But I.I.T. is also valid ABBVR and so is M.Tech'

should become

'USA is abbr  x y  is not But IIT is also valid ABBVR and so is MTech'
```

**UPDATE**: It should not be considering any numbers or special characters.

```
X.2 -> X 2
X. -> X 
X.* -> X -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
s='U.S.A is abbr  x.y  is not. But I.I.T. is also valid ABBVR and so is M.Tech, X.2, X., X.*'
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\.)(?=[A-Z])|\.', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else ' ', s))
# =>  USA is abbr  x y  is not  But IIT  is also valid ABBVR and so is MTech, X 2, X , X *
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9heUGh). Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3NL3c/3). It matches

- `(?<=[A-Z])(\.)(?=[A-Z])` - Group 1: a `.` char that is immediately preceded and followed with an uppercase ASCII letter
- `|` - or
- `\.` - a dot (in any other context)

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is an empty string, else, the replacement is a space.

To make it Unicode-aware, install PyPi regex library (`pip install regex`) and use

```py
import regex
s='U.S.A is abbr  x.y  is not. But I.I.T. is also valid ABBVR and so is M.Tech, X.2, X., X.*'
print(regex.sub(r'(?<=\p{Lu})(\.)(?=\p{Lu})|\.', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else ' ', s))
```

The `\p{Lu}` matches any Unicode uppercase letter.

Comment: Just one loophole is here. It is getting `Q.2` and `Q. ` as an Abbrevation too. How oto Mitigate that? A `. dot` must be **between TWO CAPITAL LETTERS only**

Comment: It is giving results for `'P.+ abc P.2 Q. 2 and A. B and a. a.b'` which is not desired as it is considering special characters and numbers as a part of it.

Comment: But `M.Tech` is a a valid abbreviation enclosed by two Capital letters?

Comment: @Deshwal Try `re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\.)(?=[A-Z]|\B)|\.', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else ' ', s)`. Well, your requirement is not quite clear since the `.` at the end of `I.I.T.` does not fit it. There is `T` before. but there is a space after. If you need to replace the last `.` in `I.I.T.` with a space, then you can use `re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z])(\.)(?=[A-Z])|\.', lambda x: '' if x.group(1) else ' ', s)`

Comment: Please check your expected output in the question: for `I.I.T. is`, you want to get `IIT is`, but if the [last suggested `re.sub`](https://ideone.com/9heUGh) is what you need, then `I.I.T. is` must be replaced with `IIT  is` (with two spaces between the words).

Comment: No issues with any number of spaces. I 'll have to remove the spaces in the end one way or another.

Comment: @Deshwal So, https://ideone.com/9heUGh is the right solution, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, yes. Thank you so much.