# How to remove a special character based on negative pattern matching using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a sample string of something like `hello \+ \\\world \+ \\\\ this  \234 \ is \Pattern\` and I want it to be something like `hello + \world  + this 234 is \Pattern`

One way to do is to run a loop for every character in the string and if it's a `\` and next character is **NOT** a word, then replace it with a space. Simple but inefficient code. There must be another way to do it using regular expression.

I can find all the `\alphabet` using `r'\\\w+'` and any single `\` followed by space as `\\\s+` but these won't take `\\\ \( \+` into consideration. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use:

```
\\(?![A-Za-z])\s*
```

And replace with empty string as per this online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPifvP/1)

- `\\` - A backslash (escaped);
- `(?![A-Za-z])` - Negative lookahead to assert not being followed by alphachar;
- `\s*` - 0+ (Greedy) whitespace-chars.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please [help me this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583938/how-replace-a-dot-in-sentence-except-when-it-appears-in-an-abbreviation-usin/70584011#70584011)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
\\(?=[\W\d]|$)
```

Substitute all the matches with an empty string

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QX2N8z/1)**

**[Code](https://onlinegdb.com/ZCKBYwPJh)**

**Explanation**

- `\\` - matches `\`
- `(?=[\W\d]|$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the `\` matched above must either be followed by a digit or a non-word or must be at the end of the string. All such matched `\` are to be replaced by empty string

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead:

```
s = r"hello \+ \\\world \+ \\\\ this  \234 \ is \pattern\'"

import re
s2 = re.sub(r'\\*(?![a-zA-Z])', '', s)
print(s2)
```

output: `hello + \world +  this  234  is \pattern'`

How the regex works:

```
\\*          # match any number of \
(?![a-zA-Z]) # if not followed by a letter
```

Comment: :If replaced with `' ' SPACE` It is creating space between everything except alphabets for example the string  `1233#$%^&*`